# Webservice call using IXMLHttpRequest undesired response Text

Tags: c++, web-services, winapi, xmlhttprequest

Using IXMLHttpRequest to fetch the data from the webservice.(actually, java servlets file). Using below code to send request and get response from webservice

```
IXMLHTTPRequestPtr pIXMLHTTPRequest = NULL;
CoInitialize(nullptr);
String usBuffer;
CATTry
{
    hr = pIXMLHTTPRequest.CreateInstance("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && (pIXMLHTTPRequest != NULL))
    {       
        hr = pIXMLHTTPRequest->open("POST", "URL", false);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
           String lsusHeaderName;
           lsusHeaderName.Append("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           lsusHeaderName.Append("Accept: */*");
           lsusHeaderName.Append("ticket: " + "ticketvalue");
           lsusHeaderName.Append("Context: " + "securityvalue");
            
            for (int i = 1; i <= ilsusHeaderName.Size(); i++)
            {
                BSTR bstrHeaderName;
                BSTR bstrHeaderValue;
                ilsusHeaderName[i].ConvertToBSTR(&bstrHeaderName);                  
                hr = pIXMLHTTPRequest->setRequestHeader(bstrHeaderName, bstrHeaderValue);                   
            }
            
            String iusRequestParam = "Type=xxxx&Name=xxxxytr&Revision=09";
            if (iusRequestParam != "")
            {
                hr = pIXMLHTTPRequest->send(iusRequestParam.ConvertToChar());
                
            }
            else
            {
                hr = pIXMLHTTPRequest->send();
            }
            
            {
                struct __timeb64 t_stime;   
                struct __timeb64 t_ctime;   
                long lProcTime = 0;
                memset(&t_stime, 0, sizeof(struct __timeb64));
                memset(&t_ctime, 0, sizeof(struct __timeb64));
                long nRedyState = READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED; 

                                                            
                _ftime64(&t_stime);
                while (nRedyState != READYSTATE_COMPLETE) 
                {
                    
                    _ftime64(&t_ctime);
                    
                    lProcTime = (long)(1000 * (t_ctime.time - t_stime.time) + (t_ctime.millitm - t_stime.millitm));
                    if (lProcTime > HTTP_TIMEOUT)
                    { 
                        break;
                    }
                    nRedyState = pIXMLHTTPRequest->readyState;
                }
            }
            std::cout << "Request status : " << pIXMLHTTPRequest->status << std::endl;              

            if ((pIXMLHTTPRequest->status == 200))
            {                   
                _bstr_t spbstrResponse = pIXMLHTTPRequest->responseText;
                BSTR bstrString = NULL;
                bstrString = spbstrResponse.GetBSTR();
                usBuffer.BuildFromBSTR(bstrString);
                usOutput = usBuffer;
                std::cout << "Output :  " << usBuffer << std::endl;
                bstrString = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Failed to send GET/POST Method." << std::endl;                    
                
            }
        }
        else
        {               
            hr = E_FAIL;
        }
    }
}

}
    CATCatch(CATError, pError)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to query XMLHTTP 6.0. Perhaps MSXML 6.0 is not exists." << std::endl;
    
}
CATEndTry;
```

This webservice call returns 200 status code, but response text is not good.It returns some html,javascript code as response text.

Expected result is one of the attribute value of the passed object. Example output:

{
"logy": "646F916E00005E78609AC53D0000974F"
}

Couldn't locate the issue in this code, why it returns html,javascript code.As I am new to WINAPI concepts, your help is highly appreciated.

Edit:
Checked webservice via postman and it returns expected result.

Comment: have you tried to invoke the service using a different tool, like soapui, to make sure that the problem is related to your application and not the service itself?

Comment: yes, I have checked the webservice via postman, it returns expected output

Comment: Something looks odd about the way your appending headers, what is ilsusHeaderName? - Run Wireshark & capture the HTTP request to see if it's what you expect.  You can download Postman & compare it to a working request - the difference is the problem..

Comment: Since we don't know what `CATUnicodeString` is, there's little we can do to help. At a guess, `Append` simply concatenates strings, without supplying the required CR/LF sequences. If this type does in fact add CR/LF sequences, `"Login-ticket: " + "ticketvalue"` is still wrong. It certainly doesn't do what you think it does. Your compiler likely warned about this. Adding pointers in this way isn't useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header should be passed in this way. This solved the issue.

```
CATListOfCATUnicodeString   lsusHeaderName;
CATListOfCATUnicodeString   lsusHeaderValue;

lsusHeaderName.Append("Content-Type");
lsusHeaderValue.Append("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
lsusHeaderName.Append("Login-ticket");
lsusHeaderValue.Append(usLoginTicket);
lsusHeaderName.Append("SecurityContext");
lsusHeaderValue.Append(usSecurityContext);
```